# AMCL acceptable robot speed

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using amcl. my robot speed is 40 cm/sec. AMCL probability estimation is good and But robot is losting on gmapping map. you think problem about speed value ???

my problem : ( I used 2d pose estimation button for initial pose )

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216613/amcl-acceptable-robot-speed/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2015-08-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosRabbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23646/rosrabbit/) on 2015-09-08**:
Hi, glad to meet you here. I now use amcl too.  I want to build a map using slam_gmapping and amcl. Now, I could run the two node in one launch file. But the generated map is not that good and I could not get the path when moving the rplidar. Could you give me some comments? Thanks!

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-09-08**:
but you need to ask a new question on forum. your issue is not dealing with this topic. I wrote a node for rplidar odometry path using visualization marker tools. Its not important thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my problem.  reflected light from the window caused the problem. because my area ground type is tire and light reflect from ground to lidar. and lidar can not see walls. so my map is not correct. amcl lost its position for this reason.

---

Originally posted by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) with karma: 153 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1